# Where to download Sun Solaris 10 SPARC 64bit installation cd's?

Tags: solaris

Sun has released Solaris 10 CDs for free usage / download. Now on the oracle site I can't find them. Where can I find Solaris 10 for Sparc 64bit? I have Sun Blade 1500.

Comment: Note that while the software is "free to download", under the (post-Sun) Oracle license terms you may not use it in Production without a valid support contract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle doesn't offer the CD images any more, it seems, but they do have a DVD image for download. You can either hook a DVD drive to your Blade, or mount the DVD on another system and install from net.

[Solaris 10 Download at Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html)

- link verified: 2017-10-12
- link verified: 2021-04-17 Still valid, but redirected to [Solaris10u11-get-jsp SPARC/x86 page](https://www.oracle.com/solaris/solaris10/downloads/solaris10-get-jsp-downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did the Blade 1500 come with a DVD-rom already? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html